# Submitting a form in Javascript with an eventlistener will not fire get request

Tags: javascript, html, function, search, dom-events

I have a search form from which I want to send a call to an API. I know my function is working because on submit, my console logs fire. Also, in the console, if I call my `function search("mytermhere")` I get a response back from the API, but triggering my search function from within the form event will not work. Please help!

HTML:

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">




<head>

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Liu+Jian+Mao+Cao|Raleway&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/js/solid.min.js">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="overlay">
            <h1 class="title">
                Visual Vibes
            </h1>
            <h2>search images</h2>
            <form class="search-form" type="submit">
                <input label="search" class="input" type="text" placeholder="&#xf002" value="">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src=" script.js "></script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
const input = document.querySelector(".input");
let searchTerm = input.value;
const form = document.querySelector(".search-form");

function search(searchTerm) { //does not run when called by event listener
  let url = `${URL}&query=${searchTerm}`;
  return fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
      return result.results;
      console.log(results.results);
    });
}

input.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(input);
  input.style = "font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif";
  input.placeholder = "";
});
input.addEventListener("blur", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(input);
  input.style = "font-family: FontAwesome";
  input.value = "";
  input.placeholder = "\uf002";
});
form.addEventListener(
  "submit",
  function(e) {
    let searchTerm = input.value;
    console.log(searchTerm); //outputs value in input in console
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("hi"); //outputs in console when form submitted
    search(searchTerm); //this function does not run
  },
  false
);
```

EDIT: updated to include full code

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is within the form HTML code.

The form tag does not have a "type" attribute. If you meant to add a button to submit the form, please do so like this:

```html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

In addition, your "searchTerm" variable is invalid, as far as I'm aware. There's no "input.value". You need to add either a 'name' attribute to both or an 'id' attribute to the input textbox in order to retrieve the search term.

Retrieving search term with ID:

```js
document.getElementById("id").value;
```

Retrieving search term with name:

```js
document.nameOfForm.nameOfTextbox.value;
```

If you want to make the form submittable "without a button", set the position to 'absolute' and hide it somewhere, like this:

```html
<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
```

Comment: for the last part, do you mean hide the button, not the input?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: i added in the rest of the code..  I did query select the input up top. I tried to add a button and hide it (my form doesn't have a button), but no luck

Comment: Did you remove "type=submit" from the form tag?
Also, try this for your event listeners:

$("#formId").submit(function(e) {

});